# Cassandra initial connect with gocql

Tags: ubuntu, go, cassandra

The code is written with Go and Cassandra and when I build it works good in my local computer.
But when I upload it to the server (Ubuntu 20) it throws this error

> gocql: unable to dial control conn 127.0.0.1: gocql: received unexpected frame on stream 0: [header version=[version=4 direction=RESP] flags=0x0 stream=0 op=SUPPORTED length=96]
> panic: gocql: unable to create session: control: unable to connect to initial hosts: gocql: received unexpected frame on stream 0: [header version=[version=4 direction=RESP] flags=0x0 stream=0 op=SUPPORTED length=96]
> And this is the code

```
var err error
cluster := gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1")
cluster.Keyspace = "rentminer"
cluster.ConnectTimeout = time.Second * 1000
cluster.Consistency = gocql.One
Db, err = cluster.CreateSession()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Anybody has any solution???

Comment: Can you provide your connection code?

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: Not sure if this is still needed, but in my connection setup I also have this line:  `cluster.ProtoVersion = 4 // needed to talk to cassandra 3.x`

Comment: Apart from that, I assume you are talking to the correct address ("ip:port"), and have no authorization enabled on the production cluster. Otherwise you need to do this:
`
  cluster.Authenticator = gocql.PasswordAuthenticator{
   Username: def.user,
   Password: def.pass,
  }
`

Comment: I have tried these solutions but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. gocql not work with the latest version of Cassandra so I have installed it via this link and problem solved

```
deb https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/debian 311x main
```